# User made options in adminHTML

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, system.xml

I'm making a module in which the user can add review scores from another site.

It currently looks like this.

[image: current]
And I want to add a function like this:
[image: desired]

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You need to this in system configuration or product level etc?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya These values will be displayed on the website as star rating

Comment: You need this in configuration level or product level.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya system configuration level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is what Magento defines under `adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array`.
This will allow you to create an input table in the admin with a user defined number of rows.

This is used for example in `Configuration > GENERAL > Design` and looks like this:
[image]

Add this to your Vendorname/Modulename/etc/system.xml (make sure you update the module name and node labels accordingly):

```
<config>
    <tabs>
    <vendor translate="label" module="vendorname_modulename">
        <label>Tab Name</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order> 
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </vendor>
</tabs> 
    <sections>
        <modulename_settings translate="label" module="vendorname_modulename">
            <groups>
                <label>Group Label</label>
                <tab>vendor</tab>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <some_options translate="label">
                    <label>Section Label</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <params module="vendorname_modulename">
                            <label>Table Label</label>
                            <frontend_model>vendorname_modulename/adminhtml_system_config_source_table</frontend_model>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </params>
                    </fields>
                </some_options>
                <!-- [...] -->
            </groups>
        </modulename_settings>
        <!-- [...] -->
    </sections>
</config>
```

Then, as specified in the frontend_model (=Block!) node, create Vendorname/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source/Table.php and put this inside:

```
<?php   
class Vendorname_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Table extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract { 

    public function _prepareToRender() {

        $this->addColumn('column_a', array(
            'label'     => 'Column A',
            'style'     => 'width:200px',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('column_b', array(
            'label'     => 'Column B',
            'style'     => 'width:200px',
        ));

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = 'Add line';

    }
}
```

You then can get the content of this table like always using `Mage::getStoreConfig()` - but in order to utilize the values you will have to `unserialize()` it.